# Обработчик закрытия окна для QGraphicsItem

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Есть ли какой-нибудь способ определить действия при закрытии элемента QGraphicsItem, если он является окном?

Comment: ты же вкурсе, что в Qt есть 2 языка? Уточни

Comment: Я имел в виду C++

Comment: @Данил - минимум 3 =)

Comment: @eri С++ Python что еще? Из официального

Comment: а как же qml/js ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например скрытие вместо удаление делается так

В h в класс добавить

```
protected:
    void closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event) override;
```

В cpp

```
void Popup::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)
{
#ifdef Q_OS_OSX
    if (!event->spontaneous() || !isVisible()) {
        return;
    }
#endif
    hide();
    event->ignore();
}
```

Comment: Но у QGrаphicsItem нет обработчика closeEvent.

Comment: оберни его в QWidget